# Extension of places to an algebraic closure

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $v$ a place of $K$. One often extends $v$ to a place $\overline{v}$ of an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, which is equivalent to choosing an embedding $\overline{K} \hookrightarrow \overline{K_v}$, where $\overline{K_v}$ denotes an algebraic closure of the completion $K_v$. However, I haven't found an explanation of how this extension process is done concretely. Can you help me on this one?

Comment: For every finite extension $L/K$, pick an extension $\nu_L$ of $\nu$ on $L$ (equivalently, pick a prime above the prime determining $\nu$ on $K$) such that the collection of extensions are compatible with one another. This also determines a compatible system of embeddings $L \hookrightarrow L_{\nu_L}$, and taking the union over all such embeddings gives the embedding $\overline{K} \hookrightarrow \overline{K_\nu}$.

Comment: How should one choose these extensions in order to ensure compatibility?

Comment: The extended valuation of any two extensions should agree on their intersection.

Comment: Yes, but how do I actually _do_ this?

Comment: Pick the valuation on one, then choose the valuation on the second so that it agrees on the intersection with the first. Then so on inductively, ensuring that every the valuation on each subsequent extension agrees with all that you have so far.

Comment: There are several problems with that. Firstly, why is it possible to proceed by induction? At least, I don't see why the set of algebraic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ should be countable. However, even if that should be possible, you need to give an argument, why it is possible to choose the extensions in a way you propose. For example one could imagine the following: Suppose you picked $v_1$ and $v_2$ on $K_1$ and $K_2$, respectively. Let $K_3$ be an extension of $K_1$ such that $v$ is inert in $K_3 | K_1$, i. e. $v_3$ is already determined. Why is this compatible with your choice on $K_2$?

Comment: The set of algebraic numbers is countable (roots of polynomials with integer coefficients, which are countable). Regarding your example, $\nu_3 \big |_{K_1 K_2 \cap K_3}$ is a valuation on $K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$ (in fact, the unique valuation extending $\nu$ on $K_1 K_2 \cap K_3$, since $\nu$ is inert) that extends to $\nu_3$. I'm done trying to help...

Comment: It’s true that there are only countably many algebraic numbers @BrandonCarter, but there are uncountably many algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$: Indeed, consider the set of all primes, countable, and for any subset $S$ of this, finite or infinite, consider the algebraic extension $\Bbb Q(\{\sqrt s: s\in S\})$. Different sets $S$ give different extensions, and since there are uncountably many of these, there are uncountably many algebraic extensions of $\Bbb Q$

Comment: @Lubin: You are right that there are uncountably many algebraic extensions, but there are countably many finite extensions (pick a primitive element for each). Since describing the extension of the valuation on every finite extension is enough to determine it on $\mathbf{Q}$ there aren't any problems with using induction. I do agree that AC must be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method suggested by Brandon Carter in his comments will surely work, but I think an explicit call to the Axiom of Choice will be necessary to make the process succeed.

You seem to recognize that there are two ways of attacking the question: by finding an extension of a $K$-place to $\overline K$, and embedding $\overline K$ into an algebraic closure of $K_v$, the completion of $K$ with respect to $v$. In my opinion, whichever approach you use, you’ll need AC.

I had rather use the second approach: from $K\hookrightarrow\overline{K_v}$ and $K\hookrightarrow\overline K$ you conclude that there is a map $\overline K\to\overline{K_v}$ making the triangle commutative. It’s a standard fact that a morphism $\phi$ from $K$ into an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ (not necessarily an algebraic closure of $K$) may be extended to any algebraic extension $K'$, that is, there is (in fact are many) $\phi':K'\to\Omega$.

You prove this standard fact by setting up the partially ordered set of all $(L,\psi)$ for which $K\subset L\subset K'$ and $\psi$ extends the given $\phi$. The ordering is the natural one of extension, and you just do a standard Zorn’s Lemma argument on it. You get a maximal member $(\Lambda,\Psi)$, and you then do the inductive step of arguing that $\Lambda$ must equal $K'$.

If this was too sketchy, don’t hesitate to e-mail me for details.