# Silverman's AEC, X.4: How to construct local version of fundamental exact sequence?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I need some clarification in the second last paragraph from Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. I am not sure what 'For each $v \in M_K$ we fix an extension of $v$ to $\bar{K}$, which serves to fix an embedding $\bar{K} \subset \bar{K_v}$ and a decomposition group $G_v \subset G_{\bar{K} \ K}$.'

From what I understand, we start by considering a place $v \in M_K$, it can be extended to $\bar{K}$ in various ways, we pick the one which has the property that it fixes the above embedding and $G_v$, but I don't get how we can guarantee the existence of such a place $v$?

[image: Silverman's AEC, X.4]

Could someone please break down this statement for me? I'll appreciate any help given.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2679509/extension-of-places-to-an-algebraic-closure)? The proof uses the fact that $\overline K$ is the union of the finite extensions of $K$ and appeals to the axiom of choice. If $L$ is a finite extension of $K$, then we can choose an extension $w$ of $v$ to $L$. Moreover, the set of $(L, w)$ is a partially ordered set. By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal member, which must be $(\overline K, \overline v)$, where $\overline v$ extends $v$.

Comment: The need for the axiom of choice shouldn't be too surprising: we also use it to construct $\overline K$ in the first place!

Comment: I did, thanks. But it only partially answers my question. First, I don't understand why the two things are equivalent- extending $v$ to $\bar{K}$ and $K-$embedding $\bar{K}$ in $\bar{K_v}$ which the link assumes to be true. Second, what is $G_v$ here? The link doesn't mention anything about that.

Comment: Oh, I know now what $G_v$ is, it is the set $\{ \sigma \in G_{\bar{K} \ K} | v \circ \sigma = v \}$. But again, how do we know there exists an extension of $v$ on $K$ to $\bar{K}$ which fixes this $G_v$?

Comment: For the second question, $G_v$ is the decomposition group. As in the finite case, $G_v$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline K_v/K_v)$, and the embedding $\overline K\subset\overline K_v$ defines an embedding $G_v\to G_K$.

Comment: For the first question: there is a unique extension of $v$ to $\overline K_v$ and given an embedding $\overline K\to\overline K_v$, you can restrict this extension to $\overline K$. For the other direction, you can work with finite extensions: if $\overline v$ is the extension of $v$ to $\overline K$, then for any finite extension $L/K$, $\overline v$ restricts to a valuation on $L$ and you can embed $L$ into $L_v\subset \overline K_v$ in the usual way. Since every finite extension $L$ of $K$ embeds into $\overline K_v$, so does $\overline K$.